# font awesome - "icon icon-4x" in angular material design

Tags: font-awesome, angular-material

I am new in angular material design and I want to use large icon with md-icon attribute of angular material design i.e icon-4x.

```
<md-icon md-font-icon="icon-group" ng-class="icon icon-4x"></md-icon>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done by using `class="icon-4x"`
may be this help to other

```
<md-icon md-font-icon="icon-group" ng-class="icon" class="icon-4x"></md-icon>
```